# Any compilers that does not turn large switch blocks into binary trees?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I've read that modern C++ compilers turn large `switch` blocks into binary trees for faster lookup at runtime, does this go for *all* modern C++ compilers? I'm mainly using Intel C++ compiler and G++.

Comment: Why should compilers do that, that would be not only complex but also may be time consuming in terms of making the data structures

Comment: @DebasishJana there's no datastructure, it's just a tree of `if`'s

Comment: @DebasishJana I was using a compiler 22 years ago that did this. It's not a myth. Any data structure required can be built at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way, if your `case` values are close to each other, is a jump table and this is what usually all compilers will aim for. If the values are sparse, then the compilers will usually go for the "binary-if-tree".

Best solution: Don't think about it. Just assume that a `switch` is reasonably fast. Everything else smells like premature optimization. If you really encounter that a `switch` is the bottleneck of your program, then you can only know what is generated by looking at the generated object code.

The compiler might even generate something totally different like a conditional move if you only assign a variable in each of the cases. So you can never know without looking at the generated assembly.

If you have a lot of sparse values, then using a hashtable might be faster than a `switch`, since it is `O(1)` in comparison to `O(log n)` of the "binary-if-tree".

Comment: I have a switch with >400 long integers that are the CRC-64 checksum of ISO 639 language names, I use this for fast lookup of ISO language names. The CRC-64 are pretty much spread and the switch block is not sorted in any, is this ok?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen why not use hash map? CRC-64 are hashes already, and the values could be function pointers.

Comment: @Dialecticus Tried it, but it takes some processing time to build the "index" in runtime every time I create an object instance, I don't want to waste any processing resources if I can avoid it.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: If the checksums are static (which I believe they are, otherwise, you could not use a `switch`), then just build the hash table once at the beginning. Just use a static hash table instead of one per object; it is immutable anyway.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen in that case you would have to roll your own implementation of the hash map, instead of using std's, and in your implementation you would "somehow" hard-code the entire map as one big static precompiled [perfect hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) of (CRC-64, funcptr) pairs. Just calculate index from CRC-64, and jump.

Comment: @Dialecticus Interesting.  I've heard of some experiments with perfect hashing for a switch, but I'm not aware of it actually being used anywhere.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Since you have all ISO language names in advance you can try as many hash functions as needed to find the perfect one. It could be as easy as first few bits of that CRC-64 value.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, even GCC, for example:

```
int test(int x) {
  switch (x) {
   case 0:
    return 2;
    case 1:
    return 7;
    case 3:
    return 11;
    case 4:
    return 2;
    case 5:
    return 133;
    case 6:
    return 500;
  }
}
```

got turned into a jump table on all versions of GCC that I tested, when targeting x64. (even on -O0)

"Turn large `switch` blocks into binary trees for faster lookup" is also misleading, sure it's faster than a linear `if`/`else` chain (well, unless the first items are extremely more likely than later ones), but a jump table *may* be faster.

On the other hand, a jump table doesn't deal well with sparse cases, unless you use [special techniques](http://programming.sirrida.de/hashsuper.pdf) but as far as I know that isn't really done (yet?). Also, an indirect branch is usually predicted less well by the CPU - typically it is simply predicted to always go the same way as it did the last time.

They really just have *different* performance characteristics, none of the possible implementations of `switch` win all the time. It depends.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to measure the execution time. Then you can make an informed decision if your code needs optimization.

You mention this as your use case:

> I have a switch with >400 long integers that are the CRC-64 checksum
>   of ISO 639 language names, I use this for fast lookup of ISO language
>   names.

Normally you would use one of the STL data types. For example an `std::map` or `std::unordered_set` could be worth a try in your case. The `std::map` uses a Red/Black tree and the `std::unordered_set` a hash table.

Comment: This is a comment, not really an answer to the question.

Comment: None of the STL container types affect control flow; a container type cannot, in principle.  The `switch` is control flow.

Comment: @JamesKanze How that? An `std::map` lookup results in different execution paths depending on the data it stores and the value which is looked up...

Comment: @Danvil How that? An `std::map` look up has no effect on the execution path.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Of course it does! A `std::map` is a binary tree. Depending on the value you look up the left or the right node is checked. => Different execution paths. If you disagree please provide an argument other than "it doesn't". And what does that have to do with the question or the answer anyways?

Comment: @Danvil There's nothing to argue.  A data type is not control flow in C++.  An `std::map` is not a `switch`, and it is not an `if`.  (And of course, the execution paths even within the map are the same, regardless.  It's only the data on which they operate which changes.)

Answer (score 2):

Having worked on compilers in the past...

The normal way of processing a switch statement is first to sort
the case values, then look for compact blocks, where there are
adjacent, or nearly adjacent values.  Such blocks will be
separated out, and handled using a jump table; an array of
target addresses, indexed by the value (minus the value for the
first element of the table).  Any remaining values will be
checked using a hard coded binary search.

This was standard procedure some 25 years ago.  I would assume
that if it has changed since then, it is because someone has
come up with an even better solution.  (Mathematically, it's
easy to prove that you can't achieve a better big-O in the
general case.)  A modern compiler might, for example, use
profiler information to determine which cases are more likely,
and if they are significantly more likely, test them first.